# Altering array in .then statement (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

In a double for loop I am looping through different values where I test if specific value returns an error. Predefined function returns promise and it is all okay, if I need it once. But I need a way to store all errors (errors array) and all correct states (corrects array) and hardware I am using does not allow dynamically adding text to screen so I am using arrays. But i cannot find a way to do it in .then block. I was searching for a solution online but could not find one that would solve my problem.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < idarray.length; i++) {
  type = idarray[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < maxValues[i]; j++) {
    //console.log("Type: ",type);
    //here i send new command with type and value
    var sethbt = myLibrary.NewCommand(uuid, "Param", {
      "Data": [{
        "Type": type, //number
        "Control": 1,
        "Value": j.toString() //string
      }]
    })
    //here i read the value of type
    var hbt = myLibrary.NewCommand(uuid, "Param", {
      "Data": [{
        "Type": type,
        "Control": 0,
        "Value": ""
      }]
    })
    //hbt returns a promise where i get the value, if control==2 it is error, otherwise 
    //it is ok
    hbt.then(function(data) {
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      if (obj[0].Control == 2) {
        var text = "ERROR: Type: \"" + obj[0].Type + "\" --> Value:\"" + obj[0].Value + "\"";
        //here i want to add error to array of errors, but change is not seen
        //out of .then block
        errors.push(text);
      } else {
        corrects.push("OK: Type: \"" + obj[0].Type + "\" --> Value:\"" + obj[0].Value + "\"");
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly why you are not succeeding. Do you get an error or not the desired outcome...?

Comment: I cannot see a declaration for the corrects / errors scripts. You're performing a syncronous loop with async functions inside of it. This could cause some problems. If you can post the full code, that would be helpful, but I imagine it's a scoping or async issue.

Comment: Well, i have defined arrays corrects and errors above this function. It works OK if i push something to array outside .then block. But changes in these array are not seen if i do it inside .then block. See both if and else statements.     For instance, if I write something to a div, it displays it ok, but adding values to array does not work. I know it is async function and I am searching for a solution where changes I do to the array are seen outside of this block.  var errors = [];
var corrects = [];

Comment: Main problem is that I am stuck with this NewCommand function that only returns promise so I must work with that, also my js knowledge is stil more or less on a beginner level, so I did not work with promises a lot.